# Crash free rate with unprocessed crashes

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, dsym

I have a question of how Crashlytics calucalating crash free rate?

I have some unprocessed crashes because of missing dSYMs and cannot fix it right away, but just want to know if crash free rate is still valid with this unprocessed crashes, or Crashlytics won't take unprocessed crashes into account when calculating the rate.

I've tried to find this information anywhere in Crashlytics, but was not able to.